# CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect after upgrading to django 1.10 from 1.8

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I am sending a post request via AJAX to api (both the current page and api are under the same host). I am getting `csrf failed: csrf token missing or incorrect error`. This happened when I upgraded to django 1.10 from 1.8. I checked with django 1.9 as well and error persists on 1.9. Here is the detail curl :

`curl 'https://tru-staging.com/pagemaker/api/v1/carousel/slide/' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://tru-staging.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6' -H 'Authorization: Token undefined' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'X-CSRFToken: UMQPAIb1OTl7MyiQLJttdKE8xOLz35pMaHeNGMMDqy0Jn3x8SpbaEUmzOQk7Fppr' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36' -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.2131330908.1484113382; sessionid=nnxqi67j18tblt985vayyz4ssyhdnfjm; csrftoken=o6gjW1Sxb1X23hI9RurDIAXjSuEbbgbMQJtMQyS2gT1yTnCGF80rmmB8pwSOSKKj' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: https://tru-staging.com/68/school_landing/' --data-binary '{"order":4,"carousel":736}' —compressed`

Answer (score 0):

The `X-CSRFToken` header doesn't match the `csrftoken` cookie value from the command line above. The specific error message is coming from:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L313

This indicates the CSRF tokens indeed don't match.

Comment: Whats causing that?

Comment: How are you setting the X-CSRFToken before making the AJAX call? I'm assuming you have a getCookie() function that grabs it?

Comment: I do. I am settings header like this: https://gist.github.com/sachitad/793b96e56ca719f77bae687085bcd99a

Comment: Might somethign be cached? Do the tokens match under Django 1.8?

Comment: Cleared the cache. still the same error. Yes it does match on django 1.8 and below.

Comment: Are you able to test against the app server directly (e.g. port 8000)? There was a bug that was fixed in 1.9 related to CSRF tokens failing when coming through a reverse proxy. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26094

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132888/discussion-between-scovetta-and-sachitad).